# Trouble working with nested JSON objects on Objective-C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json

On my iPhone app, I'm getting this response from the server:
[image: Server JSON response]

I need to save this data to disk, so it can be accessed while offline, and am doing it with NSKeyedArchiver.

I need to save each `id_pregunta`with its correspondent values, including the array `respuestas`, which has some objects, too.

How can I break this server response into more manageable data, so I can save it? My current approach is using NSMutableDictionary, but I just can't understand the logic behind this (I'm way too tired).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to serialize this into `NSMutableDictionary` you could just write the contents of the dictionary to a file. If you need to parse the data into objects (for whatever reason) or you want the general scalability and performance of a database you may want to look at this link to -> [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html).

However; you did not specify in what form you want the data.

Frank

Answer (score 0):

See these in [NSDictionary class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)...

```
 - (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag
```

and

```
+ (id)dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path`
```